# function that concatenates two lists python Codecademy

Tags: python, list

I am stucked at ex 18,chapter lists and function from CODECADEMY.
"Create a function called flatten that takes a single list and concatenates all the sublists that are part of it into a single list."
"1 On line 3, define a function called flatten with one argument called lists.
2 Make a new, empty list called results.
3 Iterate through lists. Call the looping variable numbers.
4 Iterate through numbers.
5 For each number, .append() it to results.
6 Finally, return results from your function."

Here is my code:

And the error:

**Oops, try again. flatten([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) returned [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4]**

```
n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
# Add your function here
results=[]
def flatten(lists):
    for numbers in lists:
        for number in numbers:
            results.append(number)
    return results





print flatten(n)
```

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Think about why you made `results` a global variable.

Comment: `results = []` only runs once, but `flatten` might run several times; if that happens, you’ll keep adding numbers to the same list. It should probably be local to (inside) your function.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good example why global variables should be avoided and the sorts of weird bug you'll get. Just put `results` inside `flatten`.

Comment: thanks for your reply..it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you declared the `results` list globally, while you should have declared it in the scope of your function.

Because `results` is outside of the function, it doesn't reset when you run `flatten()` the second time. Instead, the newly flattened array is added on top of the one from the previous run.

You should move `results` inside your function like so:

```
def flatten(lists):
    results[]
    for numbers in lists:
        for number in numbers:
            results.append(number)
    return results
```

That way it resets every time you run the function and thus returns the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Convert this:

```
results=[]
def flatten(lists):
```

to this:

```
def flatten(lists):
    results=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you data input wrong?

If you replace you first line of code 
`n = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`
with 
`n = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

The output will be

`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Also, you should place `results=[]` inside function `def flatten(lists):`

`def flatten(lists):
    results=[]
    for numbers in lists:
        for number in numbers:
            results.append(number)
    return results`